# UWP System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException when including a view in a page?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have 2 pages. One page contains another, where the Grid looks like the following:

```
        <Grid>
            <views:MapViewPage/>
        </Grid>
```

I've included the `views` namespace correctly and everything runs fine but the designer seems to be having a bit of an issue with this.

It underlines the views:MapViewPage line and says object reference not set to an instance of an object, and complains about the constructor. I don't understand why, I've done this in WPF where I've included views in another page or window so I don't understand why the XAML designer complains in UWP. I've restarted visual studio and deleted the bin and obj directories but i still see the error - builds fine and runs fine tho... and includes the view as expected...

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path but sometimes designer picks up wrong metadata. Please delete your obj and bin directories and rebuild your project. It should work

Answer (score 0):

> It underlines the views:MapViewPage line and says object reference not set to an instance of an object, and complains about the constructor.

Yep, this is common behavior, if you just create folder and make a xaml file in it then use xaml file without **build** the project, the Visual Studio will not find the specific the namespace (`xmlns:views="using:projectname.Views"`). Please try to 
restore the nuget package (right click the solution Restore Nuget Package) and  build or re-build your project before running it.